# Appropriate scheduling algorithms for harvesting Facebook pages?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I want to schedule harvesting Facebook pages at appropriate intervals. Some pages have more content ([The Simpsons](https://www.facebook.com/TheSimpsons) with thousands of comments and likes per post), others have less content ([Unsealed Files](https://www.facebook.com/Unsealedfiles), a few hundred comments and likes per post), and still other pages have to be harvested every few minutes because a real time event is going on (such as during a Hockey match, as on [Colorado Avalanche](https://www.facebook.com/coloradoavalanche)).

I'm trying to find appropriate algorithms to schedule these different types of pages. At the moment, I use a simplistic algorithm: harvest N pages over M hours. I schedule a harvest every `(M * 60 * 60) / N` seconds. I schedule real time pages using the same algorithm, except it's time shifted to schedule at the beginning of the period, and every X minutes until the end of the event.

This worked well until I started suffering from [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat): the queue which holds requests to harvest pages only empties when the harvester is ready. I don't "drop packets", hence my requests queue up behind other pages and prevent the latest requests from harvesting.

The statistics I keep track of and can use during scheduling decisions are:

- the time I scheduled each page to harvest;
- the actual time each page started harvesting;
- the volume of data that was harvested on each page;
- whether or not the page needed real time harvesting.

This problem almost seems like a [Network Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_scheduler) algorithm. Am I on the right track? What other algorithms should I investigate?

Comment: What is the constrained factor? Bandwidth? API request limits? Processing power? Network connection count?

Comment: Latency between when the request was sent and when it actually started. We also have API request limits, but they aren't that much of a problem.